Liber Abaci 1202: where is original manuscript scanned?
Where can I find the original scanned manuscript untranslated?
All I can find are translated English versions that include one scanned image or finger positions for counting numbers.

Using a link provided in the answer by @use3r6530 a 439 page (207 MB) .pdf file is currently at this URL, although I don't know how long this URL will be valid. I got the URL by email, after following the instructions for obtaining a .pdf file of the entire work.

@Dave L. Renfro Thank you very much. It's impressive to see the original manuscript with for example "signo 0 (quod ?) arabice zephyr appellatio (habit ?)"

The manuscript, Con. Sopp. C.I. 2616, from which Baldassarre Boncompagni's transcription is derived, is preserved in the Biblioteca Nazionale Centrale di Firenze.
An excellent electronic version of this codex in its entirety can be found on the Museo Galileo website, at this address.
However, one must be aware that no codex in our possession today is an autograph of Leonardo Pisano, nor a copy of the first edition of the Liber Abbaci.
All known manuscripts of the Liber Abbaci fix its composition in the year 1202. However, it is believed that all manuscripts (with the possible exception of codex Gaddi 36, which at least in part may belong to the first version of the Liber Abbaci of 1202, see here) are actually copies of a second revision (the original of which is lost) that until recently was considered with certainty to have been composed in 1228.
However, on philological grounds, doubts have been raised as to the exact date of composition of this second edition, which can nevertheless be placed in the second quarter of the 13th century (ancient sources propose dates slightly different from 1228, for example, in 1742, Domenico Maria Manni wrote in his Istoria del Decamerone (History of the Decameron) "in the Magliabechiana Library [now National Central Library of Florence] there is a work [...] on vellum by Leonardo Fibonacci Pisano, composed, he says, in the year 1202 and amended by himself in the year 1220").
Today, 19 (plus one) codices of the Liber Abbaci are known, of which nine contain all or most of the work, while the other ten contain, in whole or in part, only the last chapters. The following codices contain the work in substantially complete form (where possible, I have included a link to the scan in the codex name):
A Milan, Veneranda Biblioteca Ambrosiana, ms. I.72 sup. Parchment codex from the 13th century, ff. 125 (i.e., 125 "pages"). Work of a single copyist with rare corrections by a recurrent hand. The dedicatory epistle to Michael Scotus, chapter 10 and the final part of chapter 9 are missing.
B Berlin, Staatsbibliothek, Preussischer Kulturbesitz, ms. Lat. Fol. 418. 19th century paper codex, ff. 805. The hands of two copyists are clearly visible. On the first counterplate we find the name of Franz Woepcke, a historian of Arabic mathematics, to whom the volume probably belonged. As in G, a large part (about one third) of chapter 9 and chapter 10 are missing. The entire chapter 15 is also missing.
F Florence, Biblioteca Nazionale Centrale, Conv. Soppr. C.1.2616 (see also here). 14th century parchment codex, ff. 213. The main copyist is alternated with a second hand that, in addition to rubricating titles, subtitles and numbers, revised the text on the antigraph, correcting and integrating it.  He hands down the work almost in its entirety. Baldassarre Boncompagni conducted the editio princeps of the Liber Abbaci on this codex.
G Florence, Biblioteca Nazionale Centrale, Magl. XI.21. Parchment codex from the 14th century, ff. 286. Single hand. In addition to the indigitation figures, chapter 10 and the final part (about one third) of chapter 9 are missing. The dedicatory letter is added in the margin.
H Florence, Biblioteca Nazionale Centrale, Fond. Princ. II.III.25. Paper codex, 16th century, ff. 305. The codex consists of the union of two manuscripts made at the beginning of the 19th century, bearing two pen-numberings: an older one in the upper right-hand corner and a 19th-century one in the centre. A very confused codex with many omissions, in particular lacking the final part of chapters 1 and 2, chapters 3 and 10, the final part of chapter 9, the beginning of chapter 11, part of chapter 12 and the conclusion of chapter 15.
N Naples, Biblioteca Nazionale, ms. VIII.C.18. 17th century paper codex, ff. 285. Coincides almost entirely with G, of which it is a copy with corrections.
R Florence, Biblioteca Riccardiana, Ms. 783. 15th century paper codex, ff. 346. Without chapter 10, the final part of chapter 9 and the beginning of chapter 11.
S Siena, Biblioteca Comunale degli Intronati, L.IV.20. Parchment codex from the end of the 13th century or beginning of the 14th, ff. 224. At least three copyists followed one another in copying the codex. The autobiographical prologue and the final part of chapter 15 are missing.
V Vatican City, Vatican Apostolic Library, Pal. Lat. 1343. Parchment codex from the end of the 13th century or beginning of the 14th, ff. 173. Written in two columns by a single copyist who systematically omitted to reproduce in the margins the illustrative calculations of the operations set out in the text. Numerous corrections by later hands. Most of chapter 10 and a large part of chapter 12 are missing.
Of the ten incomplete ones, three are in Paris (Bibliothèque Mazarine, ms. 3637; Bibliothèque Nationale de France, Lat. 7367 and Lat. 7225A), four in Florence (Biblioteca Nazionale Centrale, Conv. Soppr. C.7.2645; Biblioteca Nazionale Centrale, Magl. XI.38; Biblioteca Medicea Laurenziana, Gaddi 36; Biblioteca Riccardiana, ms. 2252 and ms. D 68), two in Perugia (Biblioteca Augusta, ms. G 90) and one in the Vatican City (Biblioteca Apostolica Vaticana, Vat. Lat. 4606, folios 1-12 are badly damaged with considerable loss of text, and after f. 10 an unknown number of pages are missing). They mainly contain chapters 14 and 15 and some chapters  from 11 to 13, often with considerable variants.
A twentieth manuscript (San Juan Capistrano, ms. Gen. Sci. 6) was owned by Baldassarre Boncompagni and is described in the catalogue of Boncompagni manuscripts compiled by Enrico Narducci. It later came into the possession of Robert B. Honeyman jr. and was sold at auction by Sotheby's on 2 May 1979, and was purchased by J. G. Bergart who deposited it at the John Hay Library of Brown University in Providence, Rhode Island. Put up for auction again by Bonhams on 22 June 2011, its current whereabouts are unknown.
According to the style of the time, Boncompagni published the Liber Abbaci from a single codex, in fact the only essentially complete manuscript, the codex F (but already in 1838 Guglielmo Libri had published chapter fifteen in the second volume of his Histoire, extracting it from codex G.). Boncompagni's edition fully adheres to the reference manuscript, of which it preserves all writing errors, occasionally marking the most obvious ones with a (sic). The text is substantially correct but not the mathematical passages, particularly those involving the various species of fractions. Today there is a critical edition edited by Enrico Giusti and Paolo d'Alessandro for Olschki that collects all 19 available witnesses.

The Wikipedia article states "The first appearance of the manuscript was in 1202. No copies of this version are known." Is this claim true?

Yes, the claim is correct, the codices in our possession are copies of a second revision of 1228 (probably), I will update my answer tomorrow.

The link you provide to "Con. Sopp. C.I. 2616", does that contain all or only some of the chapters?  Also, do you know is the only access to F to purchase the following book? https://www.olschki.it/static/data/Recens/2019/66583/220516103920.pdf

The link to the galileo museum contains the scan of the codex F in its entirety

There are pictures of five pages of that 20th copy at the auction page (two double-page spreads, and one single page) as well as the outside of the book: https://www.bonhams.com/auction/19239/lot/1009/fibonacci-boethius-et-al/

Here is a link to electronic scan from Museo Galileo:
https://bibdig.museogalileo.it/tecanew/opera?bid=1072400&seq=431
You can choose the page and select Carta: 124r where the Fibonacci numbers are found in the right margin:


The 4th one definitely does not look like a 5.

@Kimball it was his way of writing 5, look at 55

@Kimball We say Fibonacci introduced Arabic numerals to Europe ... but here we see that they have changed their appearance between then and now.
